# use GREATEST in MySQL when there are null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to get the greatest value from this part of a query:

```
greatest((follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.37) or 
         (amtext.price*1.37) or 
         (nebraska.price *1.2) or 
         (tichenor.price *1.25))
```

My issue is there are null values in the tables, so this only returns null.  How do I get around this without running an update on all the tables to change the null values to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `COALESCE` function

EG:

```
greatest(
    COALESCE((follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.37), 0),
    COALESCE((amtext.price*1.37), 0),
    COALESCE((nebraska.price *1.2), 0),
    COALESCE((tichenor.price *1.25), 0)
    )
```

Comment: I need to find the greatest value of all 4 prices, not just the one.

Comment: then do a coalesce around each

Comment: This works for one record, but not if I have 200 records I need to do it for, what else can I try???

Comment: so if I understand properly, so right now you are getting `n` rows back and you want 1 row back. If so, then just wrap another greatest around your existing one, that will return only one row.

Comment: actually I am getting 1 row back, and I should be getting at least 20

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean:

```
greatest((follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.37),
         (amtext.price*1.37),
         (nebraska.price *1.2),
         (tichenor.price *1.25)
        )
```

`or` doesn't make much sense in this context.

If you assume that all the prices are greater than 0, you can convert them to 0 if `NULL`:

```
greatest(coalesce((follette_title.usedbuying_price *1.37, 0),
         coalesce((amtext.price*1.37, 0),
         coalesce((nebraska.price *1.2, 0),
         coalesce(tichenor.price *1.25, 0)
       )
```